# After Creating A new User inside RULES, I can not access to UID

Tags: rules, users

In my rule, I have an action that is "create new entity" with "user" bundle.

every thing works fine a new user create with provided information (user and email)

it's variable name is **new_user**

in next action, I unblock the **new user** and it works correctly.

but in next action when I tried to debug "new user" via devel action, It seems it doesn't collect the information of new user

[image]

I have attached the devel result. I see no UID and no other information from new user.
Also send welcome messages actions don't work and no email is sent to new created user.

Please tell me what my mistakes are.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the action to save the entity. The user only gets the UID when saved, not when created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Problem is solved with your valuable recommendation.